# Two questions about graded rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

From Wikipedia, a graded ring is a ring $R$ that can be decomposed as the direct sum
$$
R=\bigoplus_{n\geq0}R_n
$$
of additive subgroups such that $R_mR_n\subset R_{m+n}$ for all $m,n\geq 0$. Wiki then claims that $R_0$ is a subring of $R$ but does not prove this. They then claim that "by definition of direct sum", every element $a$ of $R$ can be written *uniquely* as
$$
a=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n
$$
where each $a_i\in R_i$. Here are my questions:

1. How do we prove $R_0$ is a subring of $R$? I have searched many internet sources and I cannot seem to find a proof of this fact. We know it is an additive subgroup, so it must be closed under subtraction. But the subring test requires closure under multiplication, and $1\in R_0$ as well. How can we verify these?
2. I don't understand what they mean with "by definition of direct sum". I checked Wikipedia's definition of the direct sum of abelian groups, and it is simply the subgroup of the direct product such that all but finitely many of the entries are zero. I don't see how this yields the uniqueness property. I have, however, seen this uniqueness property when working with direct sums of vector subspaces, but with the additional assumption that the subspaces satisfy
   $$(U_1+U_2+\ldots+\hat{U_i}+\ldots+U_n)\cap U_i=\{0\}.$$
   That is, they are "mutually disjoint" in some sense (I know that's not what this property is called, I'm just not sure what else to call it). Anyway, without this assumption on the $R_i$, how do we know every element $a\in R$ can be written uniquely as above?

Comment: $R_0R_0\subseteq R_0$

Comment: Just a general word of advice, don't rely on definitions from wikipedia. Consulting a textbook is better, and consulting multiple textbooks is better still. You never know when an object or concept has more than one definition that wikipedia has failed to mention.

Comment: Thank you, and yeah that's what I was doing. I figured I'd use Wiki for this post so it would be easier for someone to look it up quickly if they wanted to. All of the definitions I found were essentially the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, $R_0$ being a subring of $R$ follows from how $R_0R_0\subseteq R_{0+0}$.

As for your question on direct sums, it might be helpful to look at the finite analogue.
Given two abelian groups $R$ and $S$, the direct sum $R\oplus S$ will coincide with (as in, it is isomorphic to) the direct product $R\times S$.
The latter is a cartesian product of abelian groups, so the elements of $R\times S$ are of the form $(r,s)$ for $r\in R$ and $s\in S$, with addition and multiplication done component-wise.
With this notation, saying that an element of $R\times S$ is "in $R$" means that the $S$ component is zero. In other words, $R$ can be identified with the subgroup $\{(r,0)\mid r\in R\}$ of $R\times S$, and similarly for $S$.
Now, saying that an element of $R\times S$ can be written uniquely as a sum of an element of $R$ with an element of $S$ is to say that $(x,y)=(r,0)+(0,s)$ forces $x=r$ and $y=s$, which follows by computing the sum on the right-hand side.

In the infinite setting, this is no longer true for products only because infinite sums don't make sense in abelian groups. For example, you can't decompose $(1,1,1,\dots)\in\prod_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb Z$ into a sum where each summand lies in one of the $\mathbb Z$'s because such a sum would have to be infinite.

If we restrict our attention to the subgroup of $\prod_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb Z$ where we only take those $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ where *finitely many* of the $x_i$ are nonzero, the decomposition is true again: if we let $I$ be the (finite) set of indices $i\in I$ for which $x_i\neq0$, then $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=\sum_{i\in I}\vec x_i$, where $\vec x_i=(0,\dots,0,x_i,0,\dots)$ is nonzero only in the $i$th index.

In general, the subgroup of $\prod_iR_i$ consisting of those sequences wherein only finitely many terms are nonzero is precisely the direct sum, denoted $\bigoplus_iR_i$. Intuitively, this is the resulting abelian group where you allow elements of the different rings to be added together "freely" (if $r_i\in R_i$ and $r_j\in R_j$, then $r_i+r_j$ only really makes sense if $i=j$; if $i\neq j$, then we don't know what to do, so just let their sum be this new element *called* $r_i+r_j$). In this way, it is essentially by definition that elements of $\bigoplus_iR_i$ are uniquely given by finite sums of elements in the individual $R_i$'s.

In fact, your disjointness of direct summands from linear algebra is still valid for direct sums of abelian groups: if you identify $R_j$ with the subgroup of $\bigoplus_iR_i$ consisting of those elements whose only nonzero term is at index $j$, then $R_i\cap R_j=\{0\}$ whenever $i\neq j$.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: I can not understand the last statement which you have given for this example $R = \oplus_{n\ge 0} 2^n\mathbb{Z}$, as $4\in2\mathbb{Z}\cap 4\mathbb{Z} $

Comment: @Zach Goldthorpe After reading in wiki, a link which was provided in another answer, I feel it's just a notation for a proper subgroup of direct products of infinite group and it does not have trivial intersection property. Please do correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @LalbahadurSahu What does $R=\bigoplus_{n\geq0}2^n\mathbb{Z}$ mean to you, explicitly? Since $2^n\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$ as abelian groups, your example is just a direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the direct sum $2\mathbb{Z}\oplus4\mathbb{Z}$, which is isomorphic to $2\mathbb{Z}\times4\mathbb{Z}$. Although $4\in2\mathbb{Z}\cap4\mathbb{Z}$, each $4$ contributes differently to the direct sum, because $(4, 0) \neq (0, 4)$.

Comment: @ZachGoldthorpe I see, but what about this $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2^2}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2^3}\oplus\dots$? I had one more comment please have a look on that one as well. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @LalbahadurSahu I was hoping my previous response would have addressed both comments. The point is that the direct sum is a _particular_ subgroup of the direct product (not just "any" subgroup). The trivial intersection follows from how you identify each $R_j$ with a subgroup of $\bigoplus_iR_i$. It is then irrelevant what inclusion relations the $R_j$s have with each other. If direct summands didn't have to be disjoint, wouldn't that mean $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ZachGoldthorpe It means that if I identify $R_j$ with $(0,...,0,r_j,0,...)$, then $R_j\cap R_i=\{\bar{0}\}$, for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Exactly, and that is precisely the disjointness condition explained at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try my best to answer this but I'm not that familiar with graded rings. But the definition seems pretty straightforward.

1.: It's closed under multiplication since $R_0 R_0 \subset R_{0+0} = R_{0}$. Now suppose $1 \in R_n$ with $n \neq 0$. Then $1 \cdot 1 = 1 \in R_{n}$ but $(1 \cdot 1) \in R_{n+n} = R_{2n}$. This implies $1 \in R_n\cap R_{2n} = \{0\}$ (because $n \neq 2n$, see shibais answer) which is a contradiction since $1 \neq 0$. Therefore $1 \in R_0$.

2.: There is a distinction between an internal and an external direct sum (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Internal_and_external_direct_sums)). You used the internal definition for vector subspaces and therefore needed the extra assumption. When using the external direct sum we already think of the objects as being disjoint, therefore we don't need an extra assumption. The uniqueness property still holds, see shibais answer for a more detailed answer regarding this.